# Transposing a rows to columns in a cyclic order using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, awk

I would like to transpose rows to columns in a cyclic order and also ignoring column headers from 2nd occurrence.

For example

I have below data

```
[ID] 10
[NAME] TOM
[AGE] 25

[ID] 11
[NAME] SAM
[AGE] 26
```

Output should be like this

```
[ID]|[NAME]|[AGE]
10|TOM|25
11|SAM|26
```

I tried using the below awk command

```
awk 'BWGIN { FS="]"; OFS="|";} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i
    max=(max<NF?NF:max)}
    END {for (i=1; i<=max; i++)
          {for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) 
              printf "%s%s", a[i,j], (j==NR?RS:FS)
          }
    }' source.txt
```

I am getting the below result

```
[ID][NAME][AGE][ID][NAME][AGE]
10]TOM]25]11]SAM]25
```

Column names are getting repeated and Sam data should be in a newline.

How can I achieve this without hard coding column names and extracting it's corresponding values. I have more than 100 columns.
Appreciate your help to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

With [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), convert from "xtab" to "csvlite" format:

```
$ mlr --ixtab --ocsvlite --ofs '|' cat source.txt
[ID]|[NAME]|[AGE]
10|TOM|25
11|SAM|26
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="|"; printhdr=1 }
  NF{
    hdr=(hdr=="" ? "" : hdr OFS) $1
    row=(row=="" ? "" : row OFS) $2
    next
  }
  printhdr{ print hdr; printhdr=0 }
  { print row; row="" }
  END{ print row }
' file
```

Append the fields for the header and transposed rows to variables `hdr` and `row`
if the number of fields is not zero and print the variables when a record without fields is found. The header is only printed once if flag `printhdr` is set and
the `row` variable is also printed in the `END` block to print the last transposed row of the input file.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS='|' '
    NR==1 { for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1) ? OFS : ORS) }
    { for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS) }
' file
[ID]|[NAME]|[AGE]
10|TOM|25
11|SAM|26
```